# JQuery UI: Autocomplete. React on a select

Tags: jquery, select, user-interface, autocomplete

I found several examples in the internet but they don't work for me though.
I am trying to react on a select of a jquery ui autocomplete box.
I managed to have a valid callback of results however when I click on an entry the select event is not fired.
My code looks like this:

```
     select: function( event, ui ) 
     {
         alert( ui.item.value);
     }
```

The response come from a PHP file. I tried with a usual JSON Array with just the names of the results and after some research in the internet I changed it to an array that looks like this:

```
[{"id":0,"label":"Pinocchio","value":"Pinocchio"}]
```

But that does not work for me either. So what's wrong with it?

[edit]:
In the view:

```
$('#search').autocomplete
    ({
       source:
        function(request, response)
        {
        var input = $('#search').val();
        $.ajax(
        {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '".CController::createUrl('autoComplete')."',
                data:
                {
                    string: input
                },
                success:
                        function (data)
                        {
                            response(data);
                        },
                dataType: 'json',
                 select: function( event, ui ) {
                 alert( ui.item.value);
                }
        });
        }
    })
```

Yeah, the array looks like I posted above. But even if it looks like ["value1","value2"] the select event is not fired. The weird thing is that the results ARE displayed however a select has no effect.
So either it's the select part of the autocomplete or the array has not the correct form. But does it need a certain form?

Comment: I think you should post the full code. Where do you initialize the plugin? `$("#select-control").autocomplete({...});` and is that the source array of `autocomplete`, you're talking about?

Comment: @Schnodderbalken Hi, can you explain how did you install jquery autcomplete into react? In my code, it does not recognize `autocomplete` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [select](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-select) is an event of [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) not ajax

```
$('#search').autocomplete ({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var input = $('#search').val();
        $.ajax(  {
            type: 'POST',
            url: '".CController::createUrl('autoComplete')."',
            data:{
                    string: input
            },
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            },
            dataType: 'json'
        });
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {  //<<---- This should be passed to the `autocomplete` configuration
        alert( ui.item.value);
    }
})
```